# Using GeoJSON Services in Arcade Expression

Tags: geojson, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcade

I am trying to use an Arcade expression with GeoJSON services in a map using the ArcGIS Javascript API. The intent of the Arcade expression is to return a count of lakes that intersect a county that the user clicks on. Both the lakes and county polygons being GeoJSON services. Swapping out the lakes GeoJSON service with a ArcGIS Feature Layer service results in the expression functioning properly, returning the count of lakes that intersect the county GeoJSON service.

```
  var template = {
  title: "{LABEL}",
  content: "{expression/countyInfo}",
  expressionInfos: [
  {
    name: "countyInfo",
    title: "Marker Info",
    expression: `

    var lake = FeatureSetByName($map, 'Lakes');

    var lakeIntersect = Intersects(lake, $feature);

    var cnt = Count(lakeIntersect);

    return \` 
    Number of lakes: \${Text(cnt, "####")}   
    \`
    `
  }
  ]
};
```

I've tried changing the $map global variable in the FeatureSetByName function to the other global variables options ($datastore, $feature, $layer) but have had no luck.

Has anyone had any success creating a FeatureSet from a GeoJSON service, how did you declare it?

EDIT

Code can be found [here](https://codepen.io/WinkelTripel/pen/vYKQKaE?editors=1000)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your code when loading this layer? What do you mean by GeoJSON services? GeoJSON is a file format, not a web service standard.

Comment: @DrorBogin GeoJSON is a standard, not a file format.  You can have GeoJSON files, you can have web services that return GeoJSON. They're all "GeoJSON" if they conform to the standard

Comment: @DrorBogin yes, a link to the code has been added to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can now solve this problem with a function in arcade called Intersects(). Despite your source layers being from a GEOJSON, they are layers referenced in the map. You can use FeatureSet functions as input parameters to the Intersect to identify intersecting Lakes in the County. For example:

```
Count(Intersects(FeatureSetByName($map,'Lakes', ['*'], true), FeatureSetByName($map,'County', ['*'], true)))
```